# Convert int to BigDecimal with decimal - Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, bigdecimal

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to convert this. Here is what I want:

```
int i = 5900;

BigDecimal bD = new BigDecimal(i);
```

I need bD to be 59.00 but I can't figure out how to get this result. All I've been able to get is 5900 as type BigDecimal. Any suggestion would help, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the general case? What would be the result if `i = 5901`?

Comment: `i` could equal any 4 digit int

Comment: So if `i = abcd`, you want a BigDecimal of value `ab.cd`, whater digits for a, b, c and d? Also, can it be negative? And what should happen in that case?

Comment: Pls make the question title more specific because it's easy to get this question while trying to find how to simply convert int to BigDecimal in Java.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You haven't been very specific about the semantics you want, but it looks like

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(i).movePointLeft(2)
```

does what you want.

Comment: However, it's still a bit weird why Integer shouldn't be possible to cast to BigDecimal.